Why isn’t my flash (a Neewer TT560) working on my camera (Canon 4000D/T100)?
I recently bought a Neewer TT560 Speedlite second-hand from eBay for my Canon 4000D. The flash seems to work fine when I press the test button—it fires without any issues. However, it doesn’t fire when I press the shutter button on my camera.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

Set my camera to Manual mode with these settings:

Shutter Speed: 1/200 sec
Aperture: f/5.6
ISO: 100


Verified that Flash Firing is enabled in the camera menu.
Adjusted the flash power and test-fired it (test fire works fine).

Is there something I might be missing? Could the issue be with the camera’s hot shoe or the flash itself? Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

TL;DR: return the Neewer TT560, and if you can, replace it with a Godox TT685 II-C. Or, in a pinch, an X2T-C transmitter and a Godox TT600.
The Neewer TT560 (which is actually a rebranded Godox TT560 and was also, for a while, the Amazon Basics flash) is what is known as a single-pin manual "universal" flash.  It can only do the bare minimum of receiving the "sync" (fire) signal from a camera hotshoe and fire the flash. Nothing else. If you turn it over and look at its foot, you'll see it only has the one pin in the center.
Now look at the hotshoe of your 4000D (T100). It probably looks like this:

So the one signal a Neewer TT560 can receive from a hotshoe is the one signal a 4000D/T100's hotshoe cannot send. (Canon did the same thing to the 2000D/T7, and 250D/SL3).
The only Godox flashes that will work with that hotshoe are the TTL/HSS-capable ones, like the TT685 II or V1 that have pins for the remaining four contacts on that hotshoe and can communicate around the missing sync signal.
Alternatively, you can get the Godox X2T-C radio transmitter and mount that on the hotshoe, and that will give you a full five-contact hotshoe that can work with single-pin gear.  But it's not a great match with a Neewer TT560, because the TT560 doesn't have any built-in radio remote control. A Godox TT600 is still single-pin and manual only but could also be used off-camera and communicate over radio with an X2T-C. And you'd not only be able to fire it remotely, but also have M power control and HSS (no TTL, though).
See also: What features should one look for when selecting a flash?

In general, some hotshoe contacts tend to be tricky to aligh.  There is often some variation in dimensions that can cause problems.
The way to avoid that is to employ the locking pin: if that hits the matching hole, the contacts will be lined up.  That means that you don't screw the locking sleeve down all the way where it will fix the flash foot old-style but just shy of its own fastening position.  Then you jiggle the foot until the (spring-loaded) locking pin drops into place.  When that happens, you can then screw down the locking sleeve properly for a firm fit.
With some flashes/cameras, the center pin is the one with the largest tolerance against displacement.  When it has contact but some other pins don't, you may get "dumb flash" behavior where camera and flash don't talk to one another but the flash still fires but at full strength.
Mechanical alignment tends to be the main culprit in my experience, and letting the locking pin engage may be the easiest expedient to get it under control.

The camera in question does NOT have an ISO compliant center pin. It's simply not there. No amount of realignment is going to line it up with a pin that does not exist.
